# The first line getting added auto after running powershell script

Tags: powershell

The first line getting added auto after running powershell script. I don't want this line to be added in excel data.

```
$Csv = @"
Parameter,Status
ComputerName, DDPC1
one,1
two,2
three,3
four,4
five,5
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$NewCSV = @"
$($csv.Parameter -join ',')
$($csv.Status -join ',')
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


$NewCSV |Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv
```

Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-NoTypeInformation` parameter to your last line of code. As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2#-notypeinformation:%7E:text=False-,%2DNoTypeInformation,the%20default%20in%20PowerShell%206.0%20and%20is%20included%20for%20backwards%20compatibility.,-Type%3A):

> -NoTypeInformation
> Removes the #TYPE information header from the output. This parameter became the default in PowerShell 6.0 and is included for backwards compatibility.

The last line should be:

```ps
$NewCSV | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```